# I couldn't convert a object type column to string

Tags: python, pandas

```
Df['column']
xxx345xxxhgf447jfhf576
Djfnfjf5678
0000004444000000
Xxx88xxx888xxx8888xxx88
```

8

I tried

```
Df['column'].astype(str)

Df['column'].astype('str')
Df['column'].astype('|S')
```

Still it remains as object dtype

Comment: can you tell how you created the dataframe column

Comment: give the datatype as parameter in read_csv

Comment: still it has the dtype param

Comment: is it .xls or .xlsx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218496/discussion-between-vishal-and-aravind-balakrishnan).

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign it to the column after converting to `str`

```
Df['column'] = Df['column'].astype('string')
```

```
In [49]: df = pd.DataFrame({"column":["xxx345xxxhgf447jfhf576", "Djfnfjf5678", "0000004444000000","Xxx88xxx888xxx8888xxx88"]})

In [50]: df
Out[50]:
                    column
0   xxx345xxxhgf447jfhf576
1              Djfnfjf5678
2         0000004444000000
3  Xxx88xxx888xxx8888xxx88

In [51]: df.dtypes
Out[51]:
column    object
dtype: object

In [52]: df["column"] = df["column"].astype("string")

In [53]: df.dtypes
Out[53]:
column    string
dtype: object
```

Comment: @AravindBalakrishnan I have updated the answer, it's running fine in my system

Comment: It's not working in mycase. The column has numbers also.

Answer (score 0):

*Pandas* has been created with the primary goal to speed up and ease
**numeric** computations.

This is why among *pandasonic* types there are various versions of *int*, *float*
and *datetime*.
All "other" types (e.g. *string*, *list*) had been initially treated a **object**.

Only as late as in version *1.0* there were introduced types to hold in
a column such values as *string* or *bool* **and no other content** (to prevent
from appending a row with e.g. an *int* in such column).

When you create a DataFrame, you can pass *dtype* parameter, but unfortunately
only a **single** value is allowed, so you can not specify different
dtypes, individually for each column.

To attempt to convert each column types to these "new" dtypes, you can call:

```
df2 = df.convert_dtypes()
```

Now, when you run `df2.info()`, you will get:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   column  4 non-null      string
dtypes: string(1)
memory usage: 160.0 bytes
```

Note that the type of *column* is now **string** (not *object*
as it is the case for *df*).

Comment: attributeerror: 'dataframe' object has no attribute 'convert_dtypes. I get this error. Df=cb.convert_dtypes()

Comment: I suppose you use an older version of *Pandas*. *convert_dtypes* is a new function, introduced in version *1.0*. Probably you should upgrade your installation.